# Wordpress: How to show admin bar without wp_footer()?

Tags: wordpress

The admin bar works only when `wp_footer()` called, how to call only admin bar action without any other footer actions that included in `wp_footer()`?

Comment: you can do that with css set display none to footer . or just comment all the code in footer.php

Comment: i can't touch the theme files, because i working on a plugin.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/show_admin_bar

Comment: It's probably worth also taking a look at  wp_admin_bar_render()